# Are all cellular subsets of the disk simply connected, and vice versa?

Tags: general-topology

A subset $F\subset D$ of disk $D$ is cellular if there exists a nested sequence of closed (topological) disks $D_i\subset D$ such that each $D_{i+1}\subset\operatorname{interior}(D_i)$ and $\cap_i D_i=F$.

All examples of cellular sets I can think of are simply connected. Are there examples of simply connected sets that are not cellular, and are there any cellular sets that are not simply connected?

Comment: It seems $H_1(F) = 0$ by Alexander duality